# Helper in handlebars printing HTML tags

Tags: node.js, html-table, handlebars.js, helper

I have this handlebars code that is trying to dynamically create this table

```
<tr>
    {{#each this}}
        {{#ifCond this }}
        {{/ifCond}}
    {{/each}}
</tr>
```

Now I have a handlebars helper defined like this (sending this helper in res.render so like this)

```
'ifCond': function( state ) {
    if(state == "success") 
        return Spacebars.SafeString('<td class="tile-green">' + state + '</td>');
    else if( state == "failure")
        return Spacebars.SafeString('<td class="tile-red">' + state + '</td>');
    else if (state == "unknown"
        return Spacebars.SafeString('<td class="tile-orange">' + state + '</td>');

    else 
        return Spacebars.SafeString('<td>' + state + '</td>');
}
```

Doesn't seem to be working. Can anyone help me out in this?

Comment: I wouldn't use `this` it's reserved keyword.

Comment: Then how do i pass the current value to the helper. The current value is what "this" is having.

Comment: If `this` is a variable available in the template then it assumes you're passing in an object like this `{ this: [ array of values or objects ] } `. Can you show data structure and how you pass them to handlebars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can do this : https://jsfiddle.net/ChristopheThiry/L34f7rm2/

Template :

```
{{#each lines}}
<tr>
    {{#each columns as |column|}}
        {{#ifCond column}}
      {{/ifCond}}
    {{/each}}
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

Helper :

```
  Handlebars.registerHelper('ifCond', function( column ) {
    if(column.state == "success") {
        return '<td class="tile-green">' + column.state + '</td>';
    } else if( column.state == "failure") {
       return '<td class="tile-red">' + column.state + '</td>';
    } else if (column.state == "unknown") {
        return '<td class="tile-orange">' + column.state + '</td>';
    } else {
        return '<td>' + column.state + '</td>';
    }
    });
```

Data:

```
{ "lines" : [
   { "columns" : [ { "state" : "STEP1" }, { "state" : "STEP2" }, { "state" : "STEP3" } ] },
   { "columns" : [ { "state" : "success" }, { "state" : "failure" }, { "state" : "unknown" } ] },
   { "columns" : [ { "state" : "success" }, { "state" : "success" }, { "state" : "unknown" } ] } 
           ] }
```